# Does SignalR (v2+) work with Sticky Sessions without a Backplane?

Tags: signalr, load-balancing

Is using Sticky Sessions a supported scale out scenario?  Has anyone deployed SignalR with Sticky Sessions and were there any unexpected issues?

We're investigating SignalR for a load-balanced, broadcast based project (similar to a stock ticker) where messages latency is an important factor.  After reading though the Scale Out documentation it seems that the Backplane model could introduce significant latency in the messages, especially when message rates are high.

I've found some references implying that it would work with some side effects but not what the reliability and performance implications are.

Thanks!

Comment: Perfectly acceptable question. Upvoted to zero out the unfair and uncommented downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SignalR without a backplane, any client method invocation will only be able to reach clients connected directly to the server making the invocation.

This might be fine if you are only using `Clients.Caller` since the caller should always come back to the same server given sticky sessions. This could become an issue if you are using `Clients.All`, `Clients.Others` `Clients.Client(connectionId)`, `Clients.User(userName)`, `Clients.Group(groupName)`, etc... In these cases, any client that is connected to a server different from the one executing the `Clients...` code will not receive the invocation regardless of whether the client is connected to the same Hub, has the right connectionId, etc...

Comment: Thank you, so if our scenario is a server broadcasting updates (similar to a stock ticker) to (most) groups of SignalR users we should be ok?  For example, if we had a windows service connecting to each SignalR server and broadcasting via each hub.

Comment: Assuming you are broadcasting the exact same messages from each server, that would probably work. Just keep in mind that you will not be able to communicate with SignalR clients connected to another server without a backplane.